# WebDriver не может найти элемент, если запускать тесты через консоль maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при запуске моих тестов через mvn clean test в одном из них драйвер не может найти локатор и тест падает с timeoutException (истекает время явного ожидания). При этом, если запустить этот тест через Intellij idea то все отлично проходит, элемент находится. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить создание скриншота на падающем тесте. Думаю, он сможет пролить немного света на проблему.

Comment: добавил, к сожалению не проливает. Просто получаю скриншот страницы, на которой драйвер должен нажать на элемент(кнопку), но ничего не происходит

Comment: Т.е. кнопка там на месте?

Comment: да, на месте и в коде страницы она тоже есть. Самое удивительное, что такая ситуация только если мавеном запускать

Comment: А как Вы его лукапите? Через `ExpectedConditions`? Если да, какое условие используется?